# Need navigation and copy command help

Tags: command-line

I want is to copy a my fonts and few key files. But my old stuff is now listed as a different owner when I copy it, and I don't know where the fonts are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fonts are typically found in /usr/share/fonts or ~/.fonts (aka /home/username/.fonts)

you may have to adjust permissions to access these (how to do this is has been asked and answered previously).

The copy command is cp for more info try

```
man cp
```

If you are more comfortable with a GUI, boot off of a live media, (DVD/USB) Choose Try Ubuntu and hold the CTRL and ALT keys while tapping T to open a terminal and enter the command

```
gksu nautilus
```

hit CTRL-H to show hidden files

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open it in root?
If you can see the old files in the new 14.04 install then
try this command in the terminal.

gksu nautilus /

Next: Enter your Admin password as you would for any sudo command and it should load the root folder.

I have done this myself to gain access to files that require Root permission.

the only other thing you could do is explore using the "chmod" command to change the permissions on the folders